# Automatic MRI Segmenation of Heart over Dicom Image

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a bunch of short axis MRI images of the heart(Left Ventricle), in dicom format.
I want to do a Automatic segmentation of various structures in these images.
Does anyone know of a program I could use? (a C# would be fine also)
I basically just need a program which allows me to select a couple of
points on the images and then automatically saves the coordinates of those
points in a file.
Any help would be most appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: As @PaulR points out, how is this question materially different from your other question?